# Can't open terminal because of settings

Tags: linux, shell, debian, terminal, gnome

**Hello.** I have a problem with my terminal: I can't open it. I have done a thing like written [here](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-terminal/stable/pref-custom-command.html.en)

I have checked 'Run a custom command instead of my shell' and typed in 'echo Hello World'. Now I can't open terminal - whenever I try nothing doesn't apear, so I can't change back the settings. Any idea of how could I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There might be simpler ways around this.

---

In many desktop environments, you can run an arbitrary command via the GUI. A common shortcut for this is <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd>. Just run `gnome-terminal -x sleep 10h`.

---

Or: Login to a TTY (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F1-F6</kbd>). Run `DISPLAY=:0 gnome-terminal -x sleep 10h`.

---

Or: You might have another terminal emulator installed, say `xterm`. Run it, and then `gnome-terminal -x sleep 10h`.

---

Or:

1. Open your file manager, and go to `/usr/share/applications`
2. Find `gnome-terminal.desktop`, and copy it somewhere (your `~/Desktop`, or `~`, etc.)
3. Edit the copy (probably can be done by right clicking and choosing *Open With*, and then picking an editor)
4. Change `Exec=gnome-terminal` to `Exec=gnome-terminal -x sleep 10h`
5. The copied file should be showing the GNOME Terminal icon. If it isn't, right click it, go to *Properties* and ensure that it is executable.
6. Double-click the copy to execute it, which should launch an instance of GNOME Terminal running `sleep 10h`.

---

You now have 10 hours to undo whatever you did.

Comment: Thanks man, you saved me. I have opened `xterm` from /usr/share/applications and ran the command `DISPLAY=:0 gnome-terminal -x sleep 10` Just after this a Terminal appeared. I have closed the both `xterm` and `Terminal` I tried to open `Terminal` again and it worked perfectly! Thank you very much for the answer.

Comment: I got myself into this problem too b/c I set Custom command: script ~/terminalSessions/$(date +"%Y%m%d-%T-terminal-session.txt"). I wanted to append dateTime to script's session file. Thank you